# Nested Sorting in Java List based on two elements Using Comparator

Tags: java, list, sorting, comparator

I have a java list that i need to sort after adding objects to it. the object has three elements. a string and two integers. the class is as follows:-

```
public class ValueWords implements Comparable<ValueWords>{

//.............................................

public static final Comparator<ValueWords> valComparator = new Comparator<ValueWords>()
 {@Override
    public int compare(ValueWords v1, ValueWords v2) {
        return v1.valWord   - v2.valWord; }
   }
};
//....................................................................
private String strWord;
private int valWord;
private int phraseWord;
public int getPhraseWord() {
    return phraseWord;}
public void setPhraseWord(int phraseWord) {
    this.phraseWord = phraseWord;}
public String getStrWord() {
    return strWord;}
public void setStrWord(String strWord) {
    this.strWord = strWord;}
public int getValWord() {
    return valWord;}
public void setValWord(int valWord) {
    this.valWord = valWord;}
public ValueWords() {}

@Override
public int compareTo(ValueWords arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;}
//..............................................
}
```

i call it like this

```
 Collections.sort(valWordList,ValueWords.valComparator);
```

it gives me the sorted list as follows:-

```
 ---------------------------------------------
   strWord     valWord      phraseWord
   abcd          0             1
   abcde         0             0
   mns           1             2 
   efgh          1             1
   xyz           2             2
   zxx           2             0
  --------------------------------------------
```

i want a nested sorting like:-

```
  ---------------------------------------------
   strWord     valWord      phraseWord
   abcde        0             0
   abcd         0             0
   efgh         1             1 
   mns          1             2
   zxx          2             0
   xyz          2             2
  --------------------------------------------
```

i have followed made few futile tries but being new to java. they did not work. and they are quiet primitive to be placed here.

Comment: It's not clear how you want things to be sorted, apparently by valWord, then phraseWord, then strWord? Seems straightforward.

Comment: sir by valWord then phraseWord.

Comment: Do the first comparison. If they're not equal, you're done, return the results of that comparison. If they're equal, return the results of the second comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing your comparator to check for both values:

```
public static final Comparator<ValueWords> valComparator = new Comparator<ValueWords>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(ValueWords v1, ValueWords v2) {
        if(v1.valWord == v2.valWord)
            return v1.phraseWord - v2.phraseWord;
        else 
            return v1.valWord - v2.valWord;
    }
};
```

Comment: Using `Integer.compare` instead of just substracting the ints would also allow pairs of ints where the difference overflows.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine both in a single comparator:

```
public static final Comparator<ValueWords> valComparator = new Comparator<ValueWords>()
{
    @Override
    public int compare(ValueWords v1, ValueWords v2) {
        int result = Integer.compare(v1.valWord, v2.valWord);
        return result == 0 ? Integer.compare(v1.phraseWord, v2.phraseWord) : result;
    }
};
```

In java 8+ you can also use [`Comparator.thenComparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.Comparator-) to combine 2 comparators:

```
valComparator = ((Comparator<ValueWords>) (v1, v2) -> Integer.compare(v1.valWord, v2.valWord))
                                         .thenComparing((v1, v2) -> Integer.compare(v1.phraseWord, v2.phraseWord));
```